# Execute transaction method using Realm continues to loop on each run android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, duplicates, realm, realm-mobile-platform

In my app I am using Realm DB to store all the data in local database. I have some initial mock data which I want to show at the starting of the app. Previously I implemented begintransaction method. But after reading the documentation I have implented execute tranasction method. Beacuse this method is updating my new data easily. Now the problem is, whenever I click the option to show the recyclerview, the data is looping each time. for example I have 3 data. If I go back to previous page and again go to this recyclerview page, it becomes double, next time it becomes tripple and so on. I want to show only the updated data into the view. Like if I add 4th data iwant to show this to recyclerview. How can I stop looping on each run in my app.

Here is my code

**Person Page**

```
public class InitialData implements Realm.Transaction {
@Override
public void execute(Realm realm) {
    List<PersoneModel> person = new ArrayList<>();
    PersonModel model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name1");
    model.setCompany("Comapny1");
    model.setTitle("Title1");
    person.add(model);

    model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Company2");
    model.setTitle("Title2");
    person.add(model);

    model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name2");
    model.setCompany("Company2");
    model.setTitle("Title2");
    person.add(model);

    model = new PersonModel();
    model.setId(3 + System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setName("Name3");
    model.setCompany("Comapny3");
    model.setTitle("Title3");
    person.add(model);

    for (PersonModel realmModel : colleague) {
        realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj != null && obj instanceof InitialData;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return InitialData.class.hashCode();
}
```

}

**News Page Initial Data**

```
    public class InitialDataNews implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
    List<NewsModel> newsItem = new ArrayList<>();
    NewsModel model = new NewsModel();

    model.setId(1+System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setImage(R.drawable.image1);
    model.setTitle("title1");
    model.setDate("12.07.2017");
    model.setDetail("deascription");
    newsItem.add(model);


    model = new NewsModel();
    model.setId(3+System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setImage(R.drawable.image3);
    model.setTitle("title2");
    model.setDate("05.05.2017");
    model.setDetail("description");
    newsItem.add(model);

    model = new NewsModel();
    model.setId(4+System.currentTimeMillis());
    model.setImage(R.drawable.image4);
    model.setTitle("title3");
    model.setDate("13.04.2017");
    model.setDetail("description3");
    newsItem.add(model);


    .....


    for (NewsModel realmModel : newsItem) {
    realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return obj != null && obj instanceof InitialData;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return InitialData.class.hashCode();
  }
```

}

**Base Application**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // The Realm file will be located in Context.getFilesDir() with name "default.realm"
    //Here we setup the realm configuration.
    //Setting a default configuration in custom Application class, will ensure that it is available in the rest of the code.
    Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .initialData(CompositeInitialData.of(new InitialDataNews(), new InitialData()).build());
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
  }
```

**Add change Listener**

```
public class PersonPage extends AppCompatActivity implements PersonAdapter.PersonListListener{

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private PersonAdapter adapter;
private Realm PersonRealm;
private RealmResults<PersoneModel> personResult;

private RealmChangeListener realmListener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mycolleagues_layout);


    personRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.colleagues_recycler);

    realmListener=new RealmChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(Object o) {
            showAllPersons();
        }};
    colleagueRealm.addChangeListener(realmListener);

    setUpRecycler();
    }

 private void showAllPersons() {
    realmResult = personRealm.where(PersonModel.class).findAllAsync();
    setAdapter(realmResult);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private void setAdapter(RealmResults<PersonModel> results) {

    adapter = new PersonAdapter(this, personRealm.where(PersonModel.class).findAllSortedAsync("id"),this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: have you craeted class `new InitialData()` or `new InitialDataPersons()` or something like that?

Comment: @EpicPanda for person my classname is InitialData.

Comment: I recommend updating the question then

Comment: @EpicPanda I have given two initial data class

Comment: Are they in their own java  files or are they inside another class? If they are inside another class, then they need to be `public static class`.

Comment: I have created seperate 2 class. one for person, one for news. you mean public static class InitialData implements Realm.Transaction

Comment: yes that is what I mean (depending on where you defined the classes)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thank you, Ican see the person and news as initial data. but in exceute transaction method, if I add new person it does not make any change to new data. Unless I have to uninstall and intall it again. How can I make a notification of changed on this data

Comment: Well you *are* trying to set this data only **on first run (when db is empty)**, no?

Comment: Yes. The db is empty. and this data is stored as initial mock data to db. Now if I make any changes after storing it to db how the user will be notified about this cjhanges.

Comment: to observe changes made to the database, you can use `RealmChangeListener` that you add to a `RealmResults` that is stored as a field reference.

Comment: Where shoud I declare this listener in Main activity

Comment: see https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-notifications

Comment: @EpicPanda I have tried in this way initially . but it is not working. I have updated my question

Comment: if `PersonAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter`, then all changes made to the database will be reflected on the UI automatically.

Comment: Yes. In this case I have confusion. My PersonAdapter extentd RealmRecyclerviewAdapter. If I make any changes in the initial data how it will notified by user. because with my code I cant see any changes of the data

Comment: I think I do not understand the question.

Comment: Ok. In this case. I stored initial data to Realm DB. User can see only this data. they cannot make any changes with this data. Only I can add or delete those data. if I delete one data from initial data list. Howuser will be notified about this changes. How this data will be synchronised with the app. what is the procedure of that

Comment: Now that is a completely different question. If you want to use the Realm Mobile Platform (RMP) to synchronize Sync Realm with a Realm Object Server, then you need a completely different approach. In that case, you would set up the initial data using the Realm Browser, and then user would use a `readOnly()` on `SyncConfiguration` and `waitForInitialData()`.

Comment: OK thank you very much. May be I will think about it. If not able to solve this. I will post it to Stackoverflow. till now this is enough for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because in `onCreate()`, you run `basicCRUD(personRealm);` which adds new person models

```
            PersonModel model = new PersonModel();
            model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
            model.setName("Name1");
            model.setCompany("Comapny1");
            model.setTitle("Title1");
            person.add(model);
```

As you set id as `1 + System.currentTimeMillis()`, it will be a new object with a different primary key, and it gets inserted. If it were just `1`, `2` and so on then it'd update them as the same object.

Thankfully, Realm provides the [`initialData(Realm.Transaction)` method on the `RealmConfiguration.Builder()`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmConfiguration.Builder.html#initialData-io.realm.Realm.Transaction-) which allows you to create the initial data for the database only when the database is first created, or if the data is deleted after `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`.

```
public class InitialData implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<PersonModel> person = new ArrayList<>();
        PersonModel model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name1");
        model.setCompany("Comapny1");
        model.setTitle("Title1");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name2");
        model.setCompany("Company2");
        model.setTitle("Title2");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(3 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name3");
        model.setCompany("Company23");
        model.setTitle("Title3");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(4 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name4");
        model.setCompany("Comapny4");
        model.setTitle("Title4");
        person.add(model);

        for (PersonModel realmModel : person) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return object != null && object instanceof InitialData;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return InitialData.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```

And

```
Realm.init(this);
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                    .initialData(new InitialData())
                                    .build());
```

**EDIT:**

To provide multiple "initial datas" in only one "initial data" (as you provide 1 transaction), you can rely on the `composite design pattern` to provide multiple initial datas in just one initial data, like so

```
public final class InitialDataPersons implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<PersonModel> person = new ArrayList<>();
        PersonModel model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(1 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name1");
        model.setCompany("Comapny1");
        model.setTitle("Title1");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(2 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name2");
        model.setCompany("Company2");
        model.setTitle("Title2");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(3 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name3");
        model.setCompany("Company23");
        model.setTitle("Title3");
        person.add(model);

        model = new PersonModel();
        model.setId(4 + System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setName("Name4");
        model.setCompany("Comapny4");
        model.setTitle("Title4");
        person.add(model);

        for (PersonModel realmModel : person) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return object != null && object instanceof InitialDataPersons;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return InitialDataPersons.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
public final class InitialDataNews implements Realm.Transaction {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        List<NewsModel> newsItem = new ArrayList<>();
        NewsModel model = new NewsModel();

        model.setId(1+System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setImage(R.drawable.image1);
        model.setTitle("title1");
        model.setDate("12.07.2017");
        model.setDetail("deascription");
        newsItem.add(model);

        model = new NewsModel();
        model.setId(3+System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setImage(R.drawable.image3);
        model.setTitle("title2");
        model.setDate("05.05.2017");
        model.setDetail("description");
        newsItem.add(model);

        model = new NewsModel();
        model.setId(4+System.currentTimeMillis());
        model.setImage(R.drawable.image4);
        model.setTitle("title3");
        model.setDate("13.04.2017");
        model.setDetail("description3");
        newsItem.add(model);

        .....

        for (NewsModel realmModel : newsItem) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(realmModel);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof InitialDataNews;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return InitialDataNews.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```

and

```
public final class CompositeInitialData implements Realm.Transaction {
    private final Realm.Transaction[] transactions;

    private CompositeInitialData(Realm.Transaction... transactions) { // `of` is prettier
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    public static CompositeInitialData of(Realm.Transaction... transactions) {
        return new CompositeInitialData(transactions);
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        for(Realm.Transaction transaction : transactions) {
            transaction.execute(realm);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof CompositeInitialData; // you might want autogenerated equals instead
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return CompositeInitialData.class.hashCode(); // you might want autogenerated hashCode instead
    }
}
```

This way you can provide

```
Realm.init(this);
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
             .deleteIfMigrationNeeded()
             .initialData(CompositeInitialData.of(new InitialDataNews(), new InitialDataPersons()))
             .build());
```

Comment: But I  do not want to implent initial data in this way. Because I have another page, which also have some initial data. Is there any alternative way to do this. Also I do not want to create any class for this

Comment: EpicPanda I am sorry, The language you have used, it is not my expectation from stackoverflow. I have tried with initial data. but I have two data as initialdata. And in this way I cannot handle the problem. May be It is easier for the  people like you "Expert Developer."

Comment: Yes. But the problem that I am facing I cannot delcare two initial data in configuruartion. To avoid this I have created  public void basicCRUD(Realm realm) in Main activit and call in to oncreate method. I hae two initial data one is personinitila data and news initial data. I have not found any source of decraring two initila data in configuration

Comment: This class I have creted for second initial data. But I fail to implement it

Comment: What do you mean by CompositeInitialData here. Also Can I add third transaction in this way

Comment: It's added in the code that I added. And yes, `CompositeInitialData` takes `varags...` so it can be any number of `Realm.Transaction`

Comment: I have fixed a parenthesis being misplaced in `setDefaultConfiguration()`.